# Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError when nodes without edges are present

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Let us consider a Neo4j database with 2 node labels (`User`, and `Movie`), and 1 relationship type (`RATES`). I have some User nodes which are not connected to any Movie nodes.

Let us consider the following query:

`MATCH (u1:User) OPTIONAL MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:RATES]->() OPTIONAL MATCH ()<-[r1:RATES]-(u2:User) RETURN u1.name, u2.name`

I agree that the query might not seem useful but I wanted to understand why it throws `Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError` exception when there are `User` nodes without any edges but it works when there are no such nodes. 
To my understanding, it should return either `u` or `null` for each `User` `u`.

When `MATCH (u1:User) OPTIONAL` is removed from the beginning of the previous query, it does not throw the exception even when there are `User` nodes without any relationships.

`MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:RATES]->() OPTIONAL MATCH ()<-[r1:RATES]-(u2:User) RETURN u1.name, u2.name`

However, it returns `u` for each `User` `u` with at least one relationship. 
But I would like to get `null` for `User` nodes without relationships.

Could anybody explain me why we get the exception with the first query and if there is another way to achieve the same expected result?

Comment: Quickly, _u1_ seems define twice. Have you try to remove label _:User_ on the second clause ?

Comment: Yes, I get the same exception after removing the label. Defining `u1` twice is intentional. In the second query above, I have defined `u1` only once but I don't get the expected result, i.e. it does not include users without any relationship.

Comment: Ok, the_Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError_  message I get is **org.neo4j.values.storable.NoValue cannot be cast to org.neo4j.values.virtual.EdgeValue**.

Comment: Which version of Neo4j are you using? Mine is 3.2.2.

Comment: I tried with _r2_ identifier on the second relationship pattern and the exception is not thrown. But I don't know why. Mine is 3.3.1

Comment: I had tried it as well but it doesn't give the correct result.

Comment: Ok, I tried it on 3.3.1, and got the same error : `org.neo4j.values.storable.NoValue cannot be cast to org.neo4j.values.virtual.EdgeValue`

Comment: I'm not sure to really understand the result that you expect but maybe this query helps you : `MATCH (u1:User) OPTIONAL MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:RATES]->() OPTIONAL MATCH ()<-[r2:RATES]-(u2:User) WITH u1,u2, CASE  WHEN ((u1)-->()) THEN u1 ELSE null END as u3  RETURN u3, u2.name`

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I modified your query to `MATCH (u1:User) OPTIONAL MATCH (u1:User)-[r1:RATES]->() WITH u1, CASE WHEN ((u1)-[:RATES]->()) THEN u1 ELSE null END as u3 RETURN u1.name, u3.name order by u1.name`, and I got the expected result. But now, I am checking it in a database with more node labels, and relationships.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the exactly same problem and the answer is that you are using the same variable for two relationships in the `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses, `r1` in this case.

If the first `OPTIONAL MATCH` is successful everything should work, but if it does not match anything the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` will lead to this error.

That's why when you changed to `r2` was fine even though the first optional match may have not matched.